# How to change algorithm caption to figure caption ouside of the box?

Tags: captions, ieeetran, algorithm2e

I'm using `IEEEtran` with `\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}`. I have one pseudocode/algorithm. My caption inside the `algorithm` environment appears as "Algorithm 1". Since I only have one algorithm, I think I should be using the `figure` caption instead. What do you think and how can I force my caption to appear as a `figure` caption?

To provide information needed for the comments here is a snippet of my code:

```
\IncMargin{1em}
\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\Indm
\KwInputs{\hspace*{0.3em}sth}
\KwOutput{sth}
\Indp
this is the body of my algo.
\caption{this is my caption.}
\end{algorithm}
\DecMargin{1em}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use the `figure` option for `algorithm2e`; in this way, algorithms are put in `figure` environments and so are numbered as figures and included in the `\listoffigures`:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e}
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
  go to next section\;
  current section becomes this one\;
  }{
    go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

An image of the result:

[image]

### Update

According to comments to the original answer, `algorithm2e` is loaded with options `boxed` and `linesnumbered`; in this case, adding the `figure` option, as in

```
\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered,figure]{algorithm2e}
```

has the undesired effect that the caption is moved inside the frame boxing the algorithm. To prevent this, some additional work is needed, but since it is just for one algorithm, I think the effort is worthy.

The idea is to load the package *only* with the `figure` option

```
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e}
```

and then manually box and frame the algorithm also using `\LinesNumbered` to get the numbers:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e} 

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

Algo de texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba  texto de prueba
\begin{algorithm}
\LinesNumbered
\DontPrintSemicolon
\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
% Write your algorithm starting here
\Indentp{-1em}
\KwIn{something}
\KwOut{something}
\Indentp{1.2em}
\KwData{this text}
\KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e}
\While{not at end of this document}{read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
  go to next section\;
  current section becomes this one\;
  }{
    go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
}
% End your algorithm here
\end{minipage}%
\end{lrbox}
\hspace*{-10pt}\framebox[\columnwidth]{\hspace*{15pt}\usebox\mybox\par}
\caption{How to make algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: I used `\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered,figure]{algorithm2e}` but the caption moved inside the box. Can I move it out?

Comment: @Elnaz you can add `figure` as in `\usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered,figure]{algorithm2e}`.

Comment: I used \usepackage[boxed,linesnumbered,figure]{algorithm2e} but the caption moved inside the box. Can I move it out?

Comment: @Elnaz Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried to increase the width of the box by changing `{30pt}` in your code but I can't get it centered. I want the column width.

Comment: @Elnaz No, forget it. I found the problem and its solution. I'll post it right away.

Comment: @Elnaz please see the updated answer.

Comment: just wanted to add that I changed the `\hsize` to `\columnwidth` and the box still doesn't look the same.

Comment: in parentheses: this fig caption is centered while all of my other fig captions are aligned to the left. Can I fix this?

Comment: the box still doesn't look like before. In my algo I'm playing with indentation to bring the line numbers in a little bit so that they fall exactly below "Inputs" and "Outputs". I'll add some code to my post.

Comment: @Elnaz Please see my new update. It's better to use     `\Indentp{<length>}` to have better control over the indentation.